# Como hacer para unir campos repetidos en una consulta en postgres?

Tags: postgresql

```
SELECT con.created as "fecha",(p.nombre||' '||p.apellido) as "Nombre Completo",con.motivo_de_consulta,con."HEA",
tc.tipo as "tipoconsulta", item.descripcion as "Cargo",
af.nombre as "diagnostico", ase.nombre as "aseguradora", (au.first_name||' '||au.last_name) as "Usuario",
hf.peso, hf.altura, hf.bmi as "IMC", hf.bmr as "GEB", hf.presion_arterial_media as "Presion Arterial",
hf.presion_diastolica as "Presion Diastolica", hf.presion_sistolica as "Presion Sistolica", 
hf.pulso, hf.respiracion, hf.temperatura, 
hf.saturacion_oxigeno
FROM public.clinique_consulta as "con"
INNER JOIN public.persona_historiafisica as "hf"
ON (con.persona_id = hf.persona_id)
INNER JOIN public.persona_persona as "p"
ON (con.persona_id = p.id)
INNER JOIN public.clinique_tipoconsulta as "tc"
ON (con.tipo_id = tc.id)
INNER JOIN public.clinique_diagnosticoclinico as "dc"
ON (con.id = dc.consulta_id)
INNER JOIN public.clinique_consultorio as "cc"
ON (con.consultorio_id = cc.id)
INNER JOIN public.clinique_cargo as "car"
ON (car.consulta_id = con.id)
INNER JOIN public.inventory_itemtemplate as "item"
ON (car.item_id=item.id)
INNER JOIN public.clinique_afeccion as "af"
ON (dc.afeccion_id = af.id)
INNER JOIN public.contracts_contrato as "contrac"
ON (contrac.id=con.contrato_id)
INNER JOIN public.contracts_mastercontract as "mc"
ON (contrac.master_id=mc.id)
INNER JOIN public.contracts_aseguradora as "ase"
ON (ase.id=mc.aseguradora_id)
INNER JOIN public.auth_user as "au"
ON (cc.usuario_id=au.id)
WHERE con.created BETWEEN '2018-01-01'::timestamp and '2018-12-31'::timestamp
ORDER BY (con.created)
```

el dc.nombre tiene muchos id de consulta, entonces esto ocaciona con los inner join que que me empiece a repetir los otros objectos, entonces lo que necesito es que ese diagnostico se una con los demas objectos para tener uno solo